# How to add current git repo to vim statusline

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive, vim-airline

I'm using vim-airline and fugitive. Currently only the git branch is shown. I'd like to show both the repo and the branch.

Comment: that would take away a lot of your screen space.

Comment: please read the help for vim-airline for examples